# Tomcat directory navigation for Localhost

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, localhost

Hi I am in the process of creating a web application with jsp/javaservlet. The problem I have is opening a file that is in a different directory than my current java class. I need help to understand why it is not picking up the directory.

Note I am just creating the program on localhost until it is done then I will export it into a .war file and set the permissions with file zilla or linux commands.

I got my file location string from running my Index page and copying it from the address bar.

My Code:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("http://localhost:8080/Practical_3_JSP/inc/Data/MyData.json"));
```

The Result:

```
HTTP Status 404 -
The requested resource is not available.
```

Path Map:

Note I have tried:

```
"http://localhost:8080/Practical_3_JSP/inc/Data/MyData.json"
```

Image Location: http://postimg.org/image/xcu5y82vb/

Comment: please show the relevant files in your deployed application (I assume your web application is called `Practical_3_JSP`)

Comment: @ScaryWombat there you go. I have added a map structure image.

Comment: But that is your source code not your deployed code.  Please show your deployed code.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, but I did end up finding a solution to the problem. I can get a result by using a jsp function:

 <% getServletContext().getRealPath("/") %>